# du command errors

Tags: disk-usage

Why does *du /sys* give an erroneous result? Using the file manager, *properties* shows it has a size of 619 MB, which is feasible. But *du -hs /sys* shows 0 MB? There are smaller-sized folders such as /etc, which the file manager shows a size of 8.4 MB, although *du* shows it as 15 MB. So there seems to be a lot of inconsistency.

Answer (score 4):

Filesystems such as those typically mounted on `/sys` and `/proc` are representations of kernel structures and do not exist other than virtually.

You cannot usefully measure the "size" of these filesystems as there is none. (And on that basis, `du -s /sys` returning `0` is arguably correct.)

On a Pi here,

```
mount | grep -E '/(etc|proc|sys) '
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
```

and

```
sudo du -hs /etc /proc /sys 2>/dev/null
7.8M    /etc
0       /proc
0       /sys
```

Comment: `du`  stands for "disk usage", so 0 is exactly right.